# Coleus leaves have been slowly losing their color, whats going wrong?

Tags: diagnosis, plant-health, plant-care, transplanting, coleus

I recently planted a set of three coleuses outside (in Florida) and two seem to be doing fine but one has started losing the color in its leaves. I'm worried about it dying, can someone tell me what is wrong with it and how to keep it alive?

Here is an album with some images of the coleus, close ups of its more pale leaves and one that fell off.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/3nA1V.jpg

Comment: Good question; if could include close illustration of the tops, & leaf undersurfaces, overall height, hours of direct sunlight & hours of diffused light per day, current watering amount & frequency, current nutrient type & amount & frequency, average day & night temperatures, if transplanted into containers shown, container sizes, soil, and if some coarse gravel in the bottoms and holes in the bottoms for good aereation & drainage, could also be helpful. We encourage you to take the [Tour], and browse through the [Help], to learn more about how the site works! Thank you! Welcome to the site!

Comment: Also, you can include illustrations that appear within the text of your questions by clicking on the scenery/mountain silhouette button, and then adding images according the instructions which appear. Thank you! Welcome to the site!

Comment: Does the one with faded leaves get more (or less) sun than the others, and in particular, does it get afternoon sun?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I apologize for asking the question then disappearing, I was able to solve the problem thanks to @Bamboo's comment. The solution was lack of sunlight!

I moved the coleus into a sunnier spot and the colors came back vividly, it also came with some mild sun scald which was remedied by watering the coleus more frequently.